# MS Access, Add record when NotInList

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a combo box. The Combo Box is linked to a table. When I add an item, not in the Table/List - I ask if I want to add the new item - If yes, another forms open, with the new item already in one of the boxes.

The table linked contains more fields. The form that opens contains this fields - but they are empty when opened - no data. The fields are not required.

Problem: The data isn't saved if I only close the form - If I input data in one of the fields - the data IS saved.

How can I force an update/save even if I only close/save the form....

Existing code:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strFirstName As String, strLastName As String
    
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        If Me.OpenArgs <> "New Contact" Then
            Forms("NKTPersonnelF").PersName.DefaultValue = """" & Me.OpenArgs & """"


        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    On Error Resume Next
    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False

    
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the form with the new item in it, just set `Me.Dirty = True` in the OnOpen event.

Comment: Hi - Tried to add:

Me.Dirty = True

But then I get an error...
"In order to change data through this form, the focus must be in a bound field that can be modified"


Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strFirstName As String, strLastName As String
    
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        If Me.OpenArgs <> "New Contact" Then
            Forms("NKTPersonnelF").PersName.DefaultValue = """" & Me.OpenArgs & """"
            Me.Dirty = True
            
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Comment: ...and then I looked at the Error message, added a line "DoCmd.GoToControl "Department"" - and it worked!

Comment: As an alternative, you could also have used `Department.SetFocus` which I personally feel is a cleaner alternative to DoCmd.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this example , the reason i am using parameter query is that it work very well with quotes. while most other techniques fail.

```
Private Sub Combo1_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)

      Dim qdf  As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strtmp As String, strSQL As String
        strtmp = " Add " & NewData & "  As new item in the list ? "
 
    If MsgBox(strtmp, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbQuestion, "Not in the list") = vbYes Then
         strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblKatzinMR ( KatzinMR, Katzin ) SELECT [KatzinMR], [Katzin]"
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)
          qdf.Parameters("KatzinMR").Value = Now()
         qdf.Parameters("Katzin").Value = Trim(NewData)
           qdf.Execute
            qdf.Close
      Set qdf = Nothing
                   
        'Notify Access about the new record, so it requeries the combo.
        Response = acDataErrAdded
        
        Else
        Response = acDataErrContinue
      End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked! My question was poorly formulated - so this wasn't the answer I needed - But it will help me with my next problem - so Thank you!!